# What Dreamforce 15 Sessions are being lead by SFSE members?

Tags: discussion

I would love to know what sessions we are all presenting. I think we have a pretty smart crowd if I do say so myself.

Comment: Can we earn badges for presenting or attending these sessions?

Answer (score 21):

We can use this answer as a community wiki.

[Apex Testing Best Practice](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q300000019BHOAA2)

[Stop Changing the Trigger Criteria!](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q300000019BFlAAM)

[Unit Testing: Not Just for Apex](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q300000019BHPAA2)

[Writing Effective and Maintainable Validation Rules](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q300000011eR2AAI) with [Repeat](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q300000019VLgAAM)

[Location-Aware Salesforce1 Development with Beacons](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessions#/session/a2q300000019BHFAA2)

[Spark: jsFiddle Meets Salesforce1 Lightning](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessions#/session/a2q300000019BH5AAM)

[Salesforce1 Meets the Avengers: Marvel API Integration by Gaurav Kheterpal](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q300000019BG2AAM)

[Building Salesforce1 Mobile Extensions on iOS with Swift by Gaurav Kheterpal](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessions?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q300000019BGTAA2)

[Build consumer apps using Mobile SDK and Ionic Framework](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessions?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q300000019BGQAA2)

[Meet the Moderators - Getting to Know Salesforce StackExchange](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2026/119)

[Apex Testing Tips and Tricks](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessions?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q30000001FmKEAA0) - Community Campfire (Unconference), so no slides. More of a discussion on the tools used for creating and testing Apex.

Answer (score 17):

[Meet the Moderators - Getting to Know Salesforce StackExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessions#/session/a2q30000001FmagAAC)

- Thursday, September 17, 9:00 - 9:50
- Moscone West, Community Campfire A

> Since Salesforce StackExchange (SFSE to its friends) opened for
>   business three years ago, its 15,000 users have asked asked 30,000
>   questions, and written 38,000 answers. Like StackOverflow and the
>   other StackExchange sites, SFSE is community-driven; users vote up
>   useful questions and answers and, less frequently, vote down unhelpful
>   content. In the midst of this, the moderators, currently Matt Lacey,
>   Samuel De Rycke and Pat Patterson, act as 'human exception handlers',
>   resolving disputes and kicking spammers off the site. Join Matt,
>   Samuel and Pat for a closer look at how SFSE works, and how you can
>   get involved.

If you can't make the breakfast meetup, come say hi!

Comment: i wont be there @ DF15. but want to pass on my thanks to all u 3  moderators.. u guys r doin awesome job.. cheers.

Answer (score 10):

[Salesforce Open Source for Fun & Everyones Profit](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q30000001BWXrAAO) (Friday, September 18, 8:30 - 9:10 @ Moscone West, 2007)

I'm also a part of [Trailhead Gladiators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIT5MHgVgTY) with a whole bunch of other people. Go Team &!

- [Tuesday Session](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q30000001ASMgAAO)
- [Wednesday Session](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q30000001CSoaAAG)

Answer (score 6):

Being a Salesforce Admin Means Being a Business Analyst

- [Tuesday Session](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q300000019VLcAAM)
- [Thursday Session](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q30000001AKwDAAW)

[Making Inside Sales Hum with Advanced Automation](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q30000001BItUAAW)

I'm also part of the Trailhead Gladiators session with Alex!

Answer (score 4):

I have two sessions.

- [Hands on Training: Building Advanced Reports for Nonprofit Admins](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q30000001Luv5AAC)
- [Taking your Flow to the Next Level with Just Enough Code](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO#/session/a2q300000019BGfAAM)

Answer (score 4):

I'll be a panelist member on [From Awesome Admin to Champion Coder](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessions#/session/a2q300000019VLFAA2)
Also on [Thursday](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessionshttps://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessions?#/session/a2q30000001AKu2AAG).

Answer (score 3):

I'll be speaking at [App Exchange for Service:  Wow With Customer Service Apps](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_Sessions#/session/a2q30000000vUolAAE) which is on Tuesday, and Friday morning at 10AM!  (Lucky me!)